# How i can creat user with privilege in ubuntu 10.04 sever

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, ubuntu-10.04, linux

How can I  create users with privilege in ubuntu 10.04 server by using CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a (normal) user:

```
sudo adduser
```

Give user `sudo` rights. Default all admin users can sudo, so you can just move your new user into that group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin my_new_user
```

Or add it manually do the sudoers file (`/etc/sudoers`)

```
sudo visudo
```

And add

```
my_new_user    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about being able to run sudo and stuff like that. Well for that to happen you have to belong to the admin group.

In order to keep this user as similar to another ubuntu user as possible the full command would be:

```
sudo groupadd foo
sudo useradd foo -g foo -G 'adm,disk,dialout,cdrom,plugdev,lpadmin,admin' -m
```

The most important one here is 'admin' as that would allow the user to run sudo which is probably what you want.